# How to access the first element of std::list?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl, iterator

I have a list `std::list<T *> *l;`. this list is not null and has some values. My problem is how to access items properly? i do not need to iterate over the list. i just want the first item only.

```
std::list<T*>::iterator it = l->begin();

if (it != l->end())
{
    // accessing T
    int value = (*it)->value(); // Is this safe?
}
```

or should i check for null also?

```
if (it != l->end() && (*it))
{
    // accessing T
    int value = (*it)->value();
}
```

Comment: You are holding pointers, so check for `NULL`. Or use an `std::list<T>`.

Comment: What made you decide to use `std::list<T *>` instead of `std::list<T>` ?

Comment: Is it really necessary to use raw pointers?...

Comment: You don't need an iterator to access the first element only. You need this only when you want to access all the list elements. And the first suggestion is the correct one.

Comment: @LihO it is even better, a *pointer* to a list of pointers!

Comment: 1st rule of modern C++ programming - don't use *****ing pointers.

Comment: @LihO Actually it is not a my decision. The API that i'm using, returns a pointer of a list of pointers

Comment: @shan: Well then authors of the API are the ones to blame then :) Although it's not good to judge the interface before you know the reasons behind decisions of its authors ;) Check my answer now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are forced to use `std::list<T*> myList;` and let's say that `T` is defined as:

```
struct T
{
    T(const char* cstr) : str(cstr){ }
    std::string str;
};
```

then just use [`std::list::front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/front/) to access first element:

```
std::string firstStr = myList.front()->str;
```

Note that in this case `myList.front()` returns a reference to first element in your list, which is reference to pointer in this case. So you can treat it just like a pointer to the first element.

And to your question about the `NULL`: When you work with the container of pointers, the pointer should be removed from the container once the object is destructed. Once you start using pointers, it usually means that you are the one who becomes responsible for the memory management connected with objects that these pointers point to (which is the main reason why you should prefer `std::list<T>` over `std::list<T*>` always when possible).

Even worse than `NULL` pointers are ***dangling pointers***: When you create an object, store its address in your container, but you will not remove this address from your container once the object is destructed, then this pointer will become invalid and trying to access the memory that this pointer points to will produce **undefined behavior**. So not only that you should make sure that your `std::list` doesn't contain `NULL` pointers, you should also make sure it contains only pointers to valid objects that still exist.

So by the time you will be cleaning up these elements, you will find yourself removing pointers from your list and deleting objects they point to at once:

```
std::list<T*> myList;

myList.push_back(new T("one"));
myList.push_back(new T("two"));
myList.push_back(new T("three"));
myList.push_back(new T("four"));

while (!myList.empty())
{
    T* pT = myList.front();                     // retrieve the first element
    myList.erase(myList.begin());               // remove it from my list
    std::cout << pT->str.c_str() << std::endl;  // print its member
    delete pT;                                  // delete the object it points to
}
```

It's also worth to read these questions:
[Can you remove elements from a std::list while iterating through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/596162/1168156)
[Doesn't erasing std::list::iterator invalidates the iterator and destroys the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5274025/1168156)

Comment: isnt .front() a deleted function at present ? if so what to use instead ?

Answer (score 0):

The need for a null-check of the list element depends entirely on what can be put into the list in the first place.

If it is possible that the list contains null pointers, then you most definitely should check for for NULL before accessing the element.
If it is not possible, then there is also no reason to check.

Comment: I disagree, you should always check for NULL, especially in DEBUG/development builds. If it's not suppose to be NULL, throw an exception.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: In that case, why not also check that the pointer still refers to a valid, live object?

Comment: If I could think of a way, I would in a DEBUG build.